# NSManagedObject : having one answer of a loop instead of multiple answer from a loop Xcode

Tags: xcode, core-data, for-loop, nsstring, nsmanagedobject

i have a problem when creating a txt file from a for statement. Here is the code of the statement on a CoreData.

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
```

```
NSFetchRequest * allTickets = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[allTickets setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Place" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
[allTickets setIncludesPropertyValues:NO];

NSError * error = nil;
NSArray * ticks = [context executeFetchRequest:allTickets error:&error];

for (NSManagedObject * tick in ticks) {

    NSArray *keys = [[[tick entity] attributesByName] allKeys];
    NSDictionary *myDict = [tick dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keys];

    NSString *theDate = [myDict objectForKey:@"date"];
    NSString *theName = [myDict objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *theNumber = [myDict objectForKey:@"number"];

NSString * finalExport = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", theDate, theName, theNumber];

    NSLog(@"%@",finalExport);
```

the NSLog result print out all the entries in CoreData correctly, running each request one after the other.

My problem is that when i want to create a txt with the finalExport NSString, i only have the first request in the file.

For exemple i got an NSLog with :
01.01.2015  MYNAME 34555445
02.01.2015  MYNAME 34523445
03.01.2015  MYNAME 34115445
04.01.2015  MYNAME 34552345

But in the text file i only got 
01.01.2015  MYNAME 34555445

So how can i have a text file with all the NSLog Results

Thanks in advance for your help ;)

EDIT ++++++++++++++

Here is the rest of the code  :

```
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents directory
```

```
    NSError *error;
    BOOL succeed = [finalExport writeToFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Number.txt"]
                              atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    if (!succeed){
        NSLog(@"NOT WORKING");
    }
```

Comment: Show more code until you write to the file. I am sure you are not writing an array of entries, but just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you write an array of entries to the file, not just one entry.

Comment: here is the rest of the code when i write the file, i add it to the starting question

Comment: From your code I see that I was correct. Please add your `finalExport` to an array and then call `writeToFile` on the array.